# MySQL error with GROUP BY statement (Query error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column)

Tags: mysql, group-by

This is my query:

```
SELECT u_id, created_date,
COUNT(u_id) AS count_total
FROM table
WHERE statement='this'
GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
ORDER BY created_date ASC
```

The error that I get is:

Query error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql) but I don't know how to get this working, as now the problem seems to be the addition of DAY.

I've tried changing the `SELECT` statement to:

```
SELECT u_id, ANY_VALUE(created_date) as test_date
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

mysql 5.7 changed the default way group by works. (I'm assuming you are on 5.7 for this answer.)

Basically, because there are multiple possible values for u_id, mysql doesn't know which one you would like. As of 5.7 with default settings, it will throw the error you are seeing. The answer you referenced, has a nice diagram, check it out again. One way to get your query to return results is:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(u_id), ANY_VALUE(created_date),
COUNT(u_id) AS count_total
FROM table
WHERE statement='this'
GROUP BY DAY(created_date)
ORDER BY created_date ASC
```

The mysql manual page has a good explanation as well https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value

Comment: I thought something like this should be solution, however I still get `Query error: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.table.created_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Never mind, I misread the error. Changing the `ORDER BY` clause to `ORDER BY DAY(created_date)` fixed that error. But by changing it all date values are 'Jan 1'.

Comment: In the result array, the label for created date was literally `ANY_VALUE(created_date)` so changed the `SELECT` to `ANY_VALUE(created_date) as created_date`

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure, your field **created_date** not contain **null** or **blank space**. So, the **DAY** function can run correnctly.
check your field by this statement and see if there is any null or blank space in result:

```html
SELECT DISTINCT created_date FROM table;
```

Comment: All created_date fields have values so this can't be the issue.